# Add a link dynamically with jquery

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

I'm able to add a link dynamically on my page, but it doesn't seem to be a link recognized by my javascript code :

Javascript code to add the link :

```
 var myLink = $('<a>',{
                    text: 'My Link',
                    id : 'link-1',
                    href: '#'
                }).appendTo('#book');
```

Javascript code to access the link :

```
$("#link-1").click(function () {
            alert('link-1 clicked');
        });
```

But when i click the new link created, there's no alert.

Do you have an idea how i can resolve the issue ?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Use event delegation on() **[Event binding on dynamic elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)**

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do this with [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$('#book').on("click", "#link-1", function (e) {
    alert('link-1 clicked');
})
```

Note: This assumes that the `#book` element was already in the dom when the binding was set.

---

**Update:**

Since you're going to be adding other links, you'll need to use a common class to target those anchors:

```
 var myLink = $('<a>',{
                    text: 'My Link',
                    class : 'my-anchor', // <-- notice I replaced id with class
                    href: '#'
                }).appendTo('#book');
```

Now you can target bind to those anchors like so:

```
$('#book').on("click", ".my-anchor", function (e) {
    alert('my-anchor clicked');
})
```

**Important Note:** You cannot have duplicate `id` attribute values in your document - that would invalidate your html and cause unexpected behaviour in your JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your link before you bind the "click" event, otherwise it will not work.

Alternatively, using [jQuery.live](https://api.jquery.com/live/) to bind to events of elements which might not exist on the page.

example:

$("#link-1").live('click', function () {
            alert('link-1 clicked');
        });

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the `.live()` method is deprecated.